# JavaScript - efficiently create array of binaries strings with number of bits set

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators, bit, bit-shift

Two arguments

1. string length
2. number of bits set

example input: 5, 2

output: ["00011", "00101", "00110", "01001", "01010", "01100", "10001", "10010", "10100", "11000"]

example input: 7, 3

output: ["0000111", "0001011", "0001101", "0001110", "0010011", "0010101", "0010110", "0011001", "0011010", "0011100", "0100011", "0100101", "0100110", "0101001", "0101010", "0101100", "0110001", "0110010", "0110100", "0111000", "1000011", "1000101", "1000110", "1001001", "1001010", "1001100", "1010001", "1010010", "1010100", "1011000", "1100001", "1100010", "1100100", "1101000", "1110000"]

Eager algorithm that I created becomes very inefficient starting from length more than 20

```js
const getBinaries = (length, numberOfBitsSet) => {
    const ones = new Array(length).fill(1).join('');
    const max = parseInt(ones, 2) + 1;
    const binaries = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < max; i++) {
        let bin = parseInt(i).toString(2);
        const match = bin.match(/1/g);
        if (!match || match.length !== numberOfBitsSet) {
            continue;
        }
        const strLen = bin.split('').length;
        const zeros = new Array(length - strLen).fill(0).join('');
        bin = `${zeros}${bin}`;
        binaries.push(bin);
    }
    return binaries;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Generator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) and create arrays of indices and return at the final step the binary string.

```js
function* g(length, bits, pattern = [], i = 0) {
    if (!bits) {
        yield Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => +pattern.includes(i)).join('');
        return;
    }
    while (i < length) yield* g(length, bits - 1, [...pattern, i], ++i);
}

console.log([...g(5, 2)]);
console.log([...g(7, 3)]);
console.log([...g(21, 5)]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: that is awesome, very elegant!

Answer (score 0):

I'd see this as a combinatorics problem. One can interpret this as integer numbers that are the sum of exactly `numberOfBitsSet` powers of two. So an algorithm could look like this:

1. Create a list of all powers of two from `2^0` to `2^(length - 1)`.
2. Select all subsets from that contain exactly `numberOfBitsSet` from that set.
3. Sum up the elements of the previous sets.
4. Convert the numbers to a binary string using [`num.toString(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)
5. Left-pad the results with zeros, such that all contain `length` characters.

However, with the default JavaScript number type, this will only scale to length of `51` (the default number type's integer precision ends at about `2^51`). Afterwards, you might need to resort to the new [`BigInt` type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

Comment: Wouldn't all powers of two always contain just 1 bit set by definition? I think you might want to add a step between 1 and 2. I agree this is a better general approach though!

Comment: @nico yes, the set in (1) always contains just a single bit set, that's why in you you pick `numberOfBitsSet`-many of them in (2) and sum them in (3). This should get you the number of bits set.